# Custom Input Format when Setting an VB DateTimePicker to a certain value

Tags: vb.net, date, datetimepicker

probably an easy one but i cannot really figure it out.
In VB, i have a DateTimePicker. I am able to set a date and store that date in a different format into a database (unfortunately non optional).

I enter dates in the format dd.MM.yyyy and the code stores it as yyyymmdd in the Database nicely using

```
foo = DatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
```

The problem is the other way around: I read dates in yyyyMMdd from the database and would like to set the DateTimePicker to that value, however it must still display the value as dd.MM.yyyy.

```
DatePicker.Value = ds.Tables("items").Rows(0).Item(9)
```

does not work (the value in yyyyMMdd is stored in that table field). I also tried something like

```
DatePicker.Value = New Date("20130303")
```

with no success. How would one cleverly parse such a string to another date format? I am sure, that there is a more efficient way than as using

```
DatePicker.Value = New Date(year, month, day)
```

after splitting the string manually into a 4 byte year, a two byte month and a two byte day.

Thanks your your help.

Luke

Comment: What is the datatype of the database column? It should be a date if you store a date inside it and thus you will not have any problems in restoring the value to the DateTImePicker

Comment: It is string unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTimePicker.Value properties expects a DateTime, so you need to convert the column content (it appears to be a string) to a DateTime.

After setting the Value property it is the DateTimePicker job to display that Date in the format required by your application.

If you are absolutely sure about the format stored in the colum then you can use DateTime.ParseExact

```
Dim tb as DataTable = ds.Tables("items")
DatePicker.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(tb.Rows(0).Item(9), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now let me say one thing. Do not store dates in a text column also if you use a format like "yyyyMMdd". A DateTime value should be stored in a DateTime column

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve. It works very well. Unfortunately, i have no influence on the structure of the database.